# Observable.next() is not a function

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Hi I'm new on angular.

I don't know why I can't set new value in my Observable

My code :

```
resultJob: Observable<any> = Observable.of("PENDING");

ngOnInit() {
    this.resultJob.subscribe(result => {
        result.next("SUCCESS")
        result.complete()
    })
}
```

This code return `result.next is not a function`

Comment: What does resultJob return?

Comment: What did you import? Is it 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';?

Comment: resultJob is my variable. It's Observable

Comment: Yes ! I have import : "import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";"

Comment: Why did you think `result` *would* have a `next` method? `resultJob` isn't an observable of a promise, just of a string (it would be good to actually type it correctly, or just leave the inferred type, then the TS compiler can tell you when you're wrong).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no next() on Observable; only on Subject and BehaviorSubject, which extends Subject (and both extend Observable).

What you need to do is:

```
resultJob: Subject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>("PENDING");
```

BehaviorSubject in contrast to Subject gets initialized with a first value that gets pushed in the stream. It seems to be what you want to do.

Also result is of type string, not of type Observable. You want to call next() on resultJob, not on result (the element inside the stream). But I don't understand why you do that in the Subscribtion. You will get circular calls this way: you push a new element in the stream and react on its detection by pushing another one and so forth...

Comment: I modified my answer, see above

Comment: Thx u !  I understood

Answer (score 6):

here is sample example of observer. for more information about component interaction you can refer this doc [Component interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)

> Step 1:- **app.module.ts**

```
 import { UserService } from './user.service';
 @NgModule({
    providers: [
     UserService
    ]
 })
```

> Step 2:-
>   **user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    users: any = null;
    nativeWindow: any;
    private userAddedSource = new Subject<any>();
    userAdded$ = this.userAddedSource.asObservable();

    addNewUser(user) {
      this.userAddedSource.next({ user: user });
    }
  }
```

> Step 3:- **add this code in your component for sending data**

```
 this.userService.addNewUser({name:'xyz'}); // your data
```

> Step 4:- **On your receiver component**

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.userService.userAdded$.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data.user);
    });
 }
```