# How can I assign a number to a type 'BehaviorSubject<number>'

Tags: angular, rxjs, ionic4

How to assign a number to type 'BehaviorSubject<number>'?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55534958/behaviorsubject-of-a-type-in-angular ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the example.

you can create [BehaviourSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject) like below.

```
counter$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1);

  onIncreaseCounter() {
    let counterVal = this.counter$.value;
    this.counter$.next(counterVal + 1);
  }
```

then you can use it like below.

```
<h2>Counter</h2>
<div>{{ counter$ | async }}</div>

<button (click)="onIncreaseCounter()">Increase Counter</button>
```

check [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9jvjnq)

Answer (score 4):

You can specify a number in the parameter of [BevahiourSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject):

```js
public yourVariable = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1);
```

In your subscription, you can assign number any time like:

```js
yourVariable.next(2);
```

Comment: You need to emit the Subject not Observable. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50099587/9590251

Comment: Thanks, updated. Was a bit quick.